# Storing and accessing object array in dictionary - Swift 3 - macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, class, dictionary

So I'm not 100% sure if this is even the right way about this but I have a class that stores a few variables, I then have an array that stores theses objects.

I've been trying to put these objects into a dictionary for easy understanding so that I don't have to have several arrays, the idea being I could use the dictionary key to identify which set of arrays I want.

For example I have

```
class Player {

init(FirstName: String, LastName:String, Team: String, Pos: String, Line: Int, GaP: Int, Sh: Int, ShotPerc: Float, TOIPerG: Float, ShiPerG: Float, TOIPerShi: Float, FaceOffPer: Float, HitA: Int, HitF: Int, SavePerc: Float){
    lastName = LastName
    firstName = FirstName
    team = Team
    pos = Pos
    line = Line
    GP = GaP
    sh = Sh
    shotPerc = ShotPerc
    TOIPerGame = TOIPerG
    shiftsPerGame = ShiPerG
    TOIPerShift = TOIPerShi
    faceOffPerc = FaceOffPer
    hitA = HitA
    hitF = HitF
    savePerc = SavePerc
}
```

I then store these in separate arrays filtered by the team (only showing relevant code but I parse a CSV file into array of Player and then use filter to put them into appropriate array)

```
players.append(Player(FirstName: record["First Name"]!, LastName: record["Last Name"]!, Team: record["Team"]!, Pos: record["Pos"]!, Line: Int(record["Line"]!)!, GaP: Int(record["GP"]!)!, Sh: Int(record["Sh"]!)!, ShotPerc: Float(record["ShotPerc"]!)!, TOIPerG: Float(record["TOIPerGame"]!)!, ShiPerG: Float(record["ShiftsPerG"]!)!, TOIPerShi: Float(record["TOIPerShift"]!)!, FaceOffPer: Float(record["FOffPerc"]!)!, HitA: Int(record["HitA"]!)!, HitF: Int(record["HitF"]!)!, SavePerc: Float(record["SavePerc"]!)!))

    var FLA = [Player]()
    var TBL = [Player]()
    var DET = [Player]()
    var WSH = [Player]()
    var PIT = [Player]()
    var NYR = [Player]()
    var NYI = [Player]()
```

This seem messy ergo wanting to put them all into a dictionary but I can only get one object into it, presumably because it's wiping the key. My question is how do I get it to store all of the players under the same key?

```
var dict: [String: Array<Player>] = [:]

for (player, _) in LAK.enumerated(){
            dict = ["LAK":[LAK[player]]]
        }
        print(dict["LAK"]?[0].fullName())
```

I'm presuming it's more along the lines of

```
dict["LAK"] =
```

but I feel like I'm going in circles!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what *exactly* your problem. Read CSV? Dictionary? There is a lot of information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store to store all players under same `key` then first collect all players and then add it to the corresponding `key`.

let suppose you read player from `csv`. I am writing pseudo code.

```
   // For playerData in readPlayerFormCSV()
   // Now you will create a Player Object using data
   // player = Player(playerData) 

   // One you have the player object
   // create the dictionary where you want to store them
   var dict: [String: Array<Player>] = [:]

   // Check which team the player belongs
   // if player belongs to LAK then add it player array with team key.

   dict["LAK"].append(player)
```

> My question is how do I get it to store all of the players under the same key?

If you just want players under a single key, Just add it to the corresponding array. I would not recommend this because the purpose of Dictionary is to store "Key-Value" pairs and adding just a single key doesn't make sense. It better to use an array.

```
  dict["Your Key"].append(player)
```

Comment: also I'm really sorry but I'm not sure how to set comments with code properly! (Newbie sorry)

I wouldn't be using one key, I'd have a key for each team.

`for (player, _) in players.enumerated(){
            dict["LAK"]?.append(filterByTeam(array: players, team: "LAK"))
            dict["FLA"]?.append(filterByTeam(array: players, team: "FLA"))
            dict["TBL"]?.append(filterByTeam(array: players, team: "TBL"))
        }`

Unfortunately I'm still returning nil, I'm thinking it's best just to stick with the assorted arrays like before?

Comment: @RyanSands can you share `filterByTeam` method implementation.

Comment: Sure :) 

`// Filter Array by Team
    func filterByTeam(array: [Player], team: String) -> Array<Player> {
        let filteredArray = array.filter({$0.team == team})
        return filteredArray
    }`

Really sorry I'm not sure how to format the code with indents in comments.

Comment: Think this way, you are looping for player and then trying to find players of a same team. `filterByTeam` will return an array of player and so looping is irrelavant and that's why you are getting nil. Don't loop just do this, `dict["LAK"]?.append(contentOf: filterByTeam(array: players, team: "LAK")) dict["FLA"]?.append(contentOf: filterByTeam(array: players, team: "FLA")) dict["TBL"]?.append(contentOf: filterByTeam(array: players, team: "TBL")` This means add players to corresponding team key. Also use `contentsOf`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store multiple values under the same key. That defeats the whole purpose of `Key-Value` storage. One key should map to one value.

You can store the array of your players instead, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a dictionary.

Dictionaries should be used when you have unique keys (identifiers) for objects that you want them accessible under. In your case, you could use the player names for that, provided that they are all unique.